# ngForm submit & nested model

Tags: angular

Here is my User model

```
export interface User {firstName: string;  lastName: string  isActive?: boolean;  registered?: any;  balance?: number;  showExtended?: boolean;  email?:string;  address: {    city: string,    state: string,    zip: string  };}
```

When we use angular form ngSubmit function to submit then the city,state and zip are not nested into address object. From console.log the user object is

```
{"firstName":"Kris","lastName":"Mell","email":"mell@gmail.com","city":"Dallas","state":"TX","zip":"00034","balance":200}
```

I was expecting the console.log for the user object to be like this. with city, address and state wrapped with address and as a subobject of user.

```
{"firstName":"Kris","lastName":"Mell","email":"mell@gmail.com", address :{"city":"Dallas","state":"TX","zip":"00034"},"balance":200}
```

what could be wrong?

Here is the form

```
 <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(userForm)">
<h2>Add User</h2>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" required minlength="2" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : userFirstName.errors && userFirstName.touched, 'is-valid': !userFirstName.errors}"
    name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" #userFirstName="ngModel" />
  <div class="invalid-feedback" [hidden] = "!userFirstName.errors?.required">
    First Name is required
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" [hidden] = "!userFirstName.errors?.minlength">
      First Name should be atleast 2 characters long
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" [class.is-invalid] = "userEmail.errors && userEmail.touched" name="email" #userEmail = "ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email"   pattern ="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"/>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" [hidden] = "!userEmail.errors?.required">
        Email is required
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" [hidden] = "!userEmail.errors?.pattern">
        Please enter valid email
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>City</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" [(ngModel)]="user.address.city" />
</div>
{{user.address.city}}
<div class="form-group">
  <label>State</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" [(ngModel)]="user.address.state" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Zip</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" [(ngModel)]="user.address.zip" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Balance</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="balance" [(ngModel)]="user.balance" />
</div>
<button  class="btn btn-block mb-3" [disabled]="userForm.invalid" [ngClass]="currentClasses">Add New User</button>
```

```
onSubmit({value, valid}: {value: User , valid: boolean}) {
console.log('form submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
this.users.unshift(value);
this.form.reset();
```

}

Comment: You would actually have to show us your code. How can we know how you have built the form? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using template driven form then , all you need is `ngModelGroup` :

```
<input name='firstName' ngModel>
...
<div ngModelGroup='address'>
    <input name='city' ngModel>
    ...
</div>
```